# Best way to store TimeStamp

Tags: python, mysql, csv, hbase

I have the following TimeStamp value: `Wed Jun 25 09:18:15 +0000 2014`.

I am writing a MapReduce program in Python that reads JSON objects from an Amazon S3 location and export it to a local CSV file. The CSV file will then export data to a MySQL and HBase database. I have about 200 million records (1 TB), so I need to optimize every processing step.

What data type should I use to store the TimeStamp value in Python, CSV, MySQL and HBase database? I need to store all aspects of the TimeStamp value. My schema has 4 columns in the CSV file, MySQL and HBase database tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use long to represent time (milli seconds), so you don't bother about the `date formatting/string encoding`. It's space efficient and much easier to perform range queries.